# Como dar a uma lista de imagens o comportamento de um RadioGroup?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Tenho 2 vetores de imagens, um para a imagem normal e outro para quando ela for selecionada.
Quando selecionar uma imagem no `ListView` preciso que as outras não fiquem selecionadas.
Já tentei de várias formas e essa foi minha última tentativa:

**Activity.java:**

```
Integer vetor1[] = {R.drawable.imagem1, R.drawable.imagem2,R.drawable.imagem.3, R.drawable.imagem4, R.drawable.imagem5};
Integer vetor2[] = {R.drawable.imagemselecionada1, R.drawable.imagemselecionada2,R.drawable.imagemselecionada3, R.drawable.imagemselecionada4, R.drawable.imagemselecionada5};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        Adapter adaptader =  new Adapter(EscolhaAvatar.this,vetor1,vetor2);
        ListView listaImagens = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listaImagens.setAdapter(adapter);
        listaImagens.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

listaImagens.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                desabilitaImagem(view, position);
            }
        });
    }

public void desabilitaImagem(View v, int posicao) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        listaImagens.setAdapter(adapter);
        img.setImageResource(vetor2[posicao]);
    }
```

Minha ideia era recriar o `ListView` e deixar como selecionada apenas a imagem em `position`

Comment: Eu tiraria essa logica da sua view e colocaria no seu adapter. Você pode usar a lógica de troca de imagem dentro do adapter que vc criou. Crie um listener (implemente OnCLick) do ImageView.

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer isso no adapter de vários jeitos mas não da certo, pq preciso mudar todas as outras imagens e no adapter n tem como percorrer uma a uma pq ele cria um item de cada vez. O problema é a referência das outras imagens que eu não tenho

Comment: Então ai vc chama o método notifyDataSetChanged do adapter ele atualiza a lista.

Comment: vocẽ precisa bolar uma forma para saber qual imagem está selecionada para poder mudar a imagem das outras no getView

Comment: da pra vc criar uma variavel int que guarda a posição da imagem que está selecionada. ai toda vez que o getView é chamado vc verifica se o primeiro parametro (position) é igual o valor da sua variavel. se for igual ele usa a imagem selecionada, se não ele usa a imagem normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com a ajuda de duas classes é simples implementar o que pretende.

Uma classe para encapsular uma *ImageView* com os estados seleccionada/não seleccionada.
Ela é responsável por guardar o estado e os *resources ids* das imagens de cada um dos estados:

**SelectableImage.java**

```
public class SelectableImage {

    private final int selectedImageResource;
    private final int unSelectedImageResource;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public SelectableImage(int selectedImageResource, int unSelectedImageResource){

        this.selectedImageResource = selectedImageResource;
        this.unSelectedImageResource = unSelectedImageResource;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public int getImageResource(){
        return isSelected ? selectedImageResource : unSelectedImageResource;
    }
}
```

Como, num conjunto(lista) de imagens, apenas pode haver uma imagem seleccionada, criamos um classe para gerir essa situação.
Ela é responsável por guardar a lista de *SelectableImage* e garantir que, quando uma é seleccionada, a anterior é desseleccionada:

**SelectableImageGroup.java**

```
public class SelectableImageGroup {

    private ArrayList<SelectableImage> list;
    private SelectableImage selectedImage;

    public SelectableImageGroup(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(SelectableImage selectableImage){
        list.add(selectableImage);
    }

    public void setSelectedImage(SelectableImage selectedImage){
        if(this.selectedImage == selectedImage)return;
        if(!list.contains(selectedImage))throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if (this.selectedImage != null) {
            this.selectedImage.setSelected(false);
        }
        selectedImage.setSelected(true);
        this.selectedImage = selectedImage;
    }

    public void setSelectedPosition(int position){
        SelectableImage selectedImage = list.get(position);
        setSelectedImage(selectedImage);
    }

    public ArrayList<SelectableImage> getArray(){
        return list;
    }
}
```

Agora é só implementar a *ListView* da forma habitual.

***Adapter:*** **SelectableImageGroupAdapter.java**

```
public class SelectableImageGroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SelectableImage> {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private final Context context;
    private final int listItemResource;
    private final SelectableImageGroup selectableImageGroup;

    public SelectableImageGroupAdapter(Context context, int listItemResource,
                                       SelectableImageGroup selectableImageGroup) {
        super(context, listItemResource, selectableImageGroup.getArray());

        this.context = context;
        this.listItemResource = listItemResource;
        this.selectableImageGroup = selectableImageGroup;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(listItemResource, parent, false);
        }

        final SelectableImage selectableImage = getItem(position);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageResource(selectableImage.getImageResource());

        //Ver nota
        /*imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectableImageGroup.setSelectedImage(selectableImage);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });*/

        return view;
    }
}
```

***Layout da Activity:*** **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Cada item da ListView tem de ter uma *ImageView*

***Layout do item:*** **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Para usar:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SelectableImageGroup selectableImageGroup;
    private SelectableImageGroupAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        selectableImageGroup = new SelectableImageGroup();
        selectableImageGroup.add(new SelectableImage(R.drawable.imagem1,
                                                     R.drawable.imagemselecionada1));
        selectableImageGroup.add(new SelectableImage(R.drawable.imagem2,
                                                     R.drawable.imagemselecionada2));
        selectableImageGroup.add(new SelectableImage(R.drawable.imagem3,
                                                     R.drawable.imagemselecionada3));
        selectableImageGroup.add(new SelectableImage(R.drawable.imagem4,
                                                     R.drawable.imagemselecionada4));
        selectableImageGroup.add(new SelectableImage(R.drawable.imagem5,
                                                     R.drawable.imagemselecionada5));

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new SelectableImageGroupAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, selectableImageGroup);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //****  Ver nota ******
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectableImageGroup.setSelectedPosition(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    //*********************
    }
}
```

**Nota:**

Da forma como está o código o que faz alternar entre o estado seleccionada e desseleccionado é um clique na linha da *ListView*.
Se quiser que essa alternância seja apenas efectuada ao clicar na *ImageView*,  "comente" o código indicado na *Activity* e "descomente" o código indicado no *adapter*

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigada!